# References using nameref disappeared after titlesec update

Tags: titlesec, nameref

With the latest update of the titlesec package (from v2.14 to v2.15) all references using `nameref` disappeared. I think this is a bug?

This MWE shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{This is my section}
\label{label:thisisthelabel}

This is my reference: \nameref{label:thisisthelabel}

\end{document}
```

Note: This seems to be related to the following reported issue [@currentlabelname is not correctly sanitized](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, titlesec fixed the case, when the `\label` is in the section argument, but broke the case when it is outside. Make a bug report at https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter

\def\ttl@sanitizedlabel#1\@@\@@{%
  \in@{\label}{#1}%
  \ifin@
    \ttl@sanitizedlabel@i#1\@@\@@
    \expandafter\ttl@sanitizedlabel\@currentlabelname\@@\@@
  \else                      % <--------- missing   
   \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%  <---------missing
  \fi}
\makeatother  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{This is my section 1}\label{label:thisisthelabel-1}

\section{This is my section 2\label{label:thisisthelabel-2}} 

This is my reference: \nameref{label:thisisthelabel-1}

This is my reference: \nameref{label:thisisthelabel-2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just opened the bug report: https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/71

Comment: Thanks. I’ll revert the change in a few days.

Comment: @JavierBezos why revert? You are only missing an \else clause to get both variants working.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for pointing this out to me. Sadly, I can't dedicate time to maintaining `titlesec` right now.